# Difference between "char" and "String" in Java

Tags: java, string, char

I am reading a book for Java that I am trying to learn, and I have a question. I can't understand what is the difference between the variable type `char` and `String`. For example, there is a difference between `int` and `short`, the bytes at the memory and the area of numbers that they have.

But what is the difference between `char` and `String`? except that `char` use (') and "String" (").

PS: It is my first "real" programming language. (At school I learned a fake-language for the purpose of the programming lesson.)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @MartinJames - I wonder if you'd make a similar statement towards JavaScript nowadays...

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`char` is one character. `String` is zero or more characters.

`char` is a primitive type. `String` is a class.

```
char c = 'a';
String s = "Hi!";
```

Note the single quotes for `char`, and double quotes for `String`.

Comment: A character constant has an equivalent integer value, whereas a single-character string constant does not have an equivalent integer value.

Answer (score 24):

`char` means single character. In java it is UTF-16 character.
`String` can be thought as an array of chars.

So, imagine "Android" string. It consists of `'A', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'o', 'i'` and again `'d'` characters.

`char` is a primitive type in java and `String` is a class, which encapsulates array of `chars`.

Answer (score 7):

In layman's term, `char` is a letter, while `String` is a collection of letter (or a word). The distinction of `'` and `"` is important, as `'Test'` is illegal in Java.

`char` is a primitive type, `String` is a class

Answer (score 2):

`char` is a primitive type, and it can hold a single character.

`String` is instead a reference type, thus a full-blown object. It can hold any number of characters
(internally, `String` objects save them in a `char` array).

Primitive types in Java have advantages in term of speed and memory footprint. But they are not real objects, so there are some possibilities you lose using them. They cannot be used as Generic type parameters, they could not have methods or fields, and so on.

However, every Java primitive type has a corresponding full-blown object, and the conversion between them is done automagically by the compiler (this is called autoboxing).

You can for example do:

```
int i=12;
Integer l=i;
```

The compiler takes care of converting the `int` to a `Integer`.

Comment: You can also compare a *char* whith *int* : in ASCII table number give you the symbol to print.

Answer (score 1):

char have any but one character (letters, numbers,...)

```
char example = 'x';
```

string can have zero characters or as many as you want

```
String example = "Here you can have anything";
```

Answer (score 0):

A char holds a single character, while a string holds lots of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Char is a single alphabet where as String is a sequence of characters.
Char is primitive datatype where as String is a class.

Comment: A `char` does not contain an entire aphabet.

Answer (score 0):

char is a primitive type, and it can hold a single character. String is instead a reference type, thus a full-blown object.

Answer (score -1):

Well, `char` (or its wrapper class `Character`) means a single character, i.e. you can't write `'ab'` whereas `String` is a text consisting of a number of characters and you can think of a string a an array of characters (in fact the `String` class has a member `char[] value`).

You could work with plain `char` arrays but that's quite tedious and thus the `String` class is there to provide a convenient way for working with texts.

Answer (score -1):

A char simply contains a single alphabet and a string has a full word or number of words woth having a escape sequence inserted in the end automatically to tell the compiler that string has been ended here.(0)

Comment: A char does not contain an entire aphabet.

Answer (score -1):

A char consists of a single character and should be specified in single quotes. It can contain an alphabetic, numerical or even special character. below are a few examples:

```
char a = '4';
char b = '$';
char c = 'B';
```

A String defines a line can be used which is specified in double quotes. Below are a few examples:

```
String a = "Hello World";
String b = "1234";
String c = "%%";
```

Answer (score -2):

In string we can store multiple char.
e.g.
`char ch='a';`

```
String s="a";
```

String s1="aaaa";

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Why this answer is negatively voted by 2 people? Can anybody explain? Is this information wrong?

Answer (score -3):

In terms of ASCII values you can say char is a single ASCII value ranging from 0-255. Whereas String is a collection of ASCII values.
Try this code to learn better.

```
        char c='a';
        String s="a b c d e f g hijkl";
        int i=c;
        System.out.println(i);
        for(int count=0;count<s.length();count++){
            int temp=s.charAt(count);
            System.out.print(temp+" ");
        }
```

The output will be:

97

97 32 98 32 99 32 100 32 101 32 102 32 103 32 104 105 106 107 108

Since 97 is the ASCII value for small 'a'. 32 is the ASCII value for space. Hope this helps in-depth understanding of the concept.

Comment: No, you can't say that. A Java `char` is 16 bits, and a `String` is a collection of `char`. Java uses UTF-16 internally, not ASCII. This is rather basic.

Answer (score -5):

A character is anything that you can type such as letters,digits,punctuations and spaces.                                                    Strings appears in variables.i.e they are text items in perls.                 A character consist of 16bits.       While the lenght of a string is unlimited.

Comment: 'they are text items in perls' is either incorrect in a Java context, or irrelevant, or meaningless. I can't decide which.