# Getting a char(36) UUID from MySQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, string

What type should I be getting for a char(36) UUID value in a MySQL query?

**Query:**

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT uuid FROM playerdata");
```

**String variable:**

```
String uuid = res.getString("uuid");
```

The above line is the part I am unsure about. Is a `CHAR` value a String, an Object, or something else?

**Example value:**

```
456f5080-f3b5-11e3-ac10-0800200c9a66
```

I've tried both strings and objects, but neither seem to work. Just a quick clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "neither seems to work" is a very poor description of your problem. Post the exact and complete error message/stacktrace you got.

Answer (score 2):

Char(36) refers to the datatype of the field in your database.  You can store strings up to 36 characters.  If you store less than 36 characters, your database will store trailing zeros.  In your case, it appears that you are storing UUIDs there, which are 36 character strings.

Since you tagged this as java, you can [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430043/difference-between-char-and-string-at-java) to see what char means in java.

In other contexts, char(36) is a function that will return a dollar sign.  The argument of that function has to be an integer and is treated as an ascii code.  Sql Server is one such context.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a normal string only.

Comment: At the time this was posted, Amar did not have a high enough rep to post comments.  My vote solved that problem.  Let's hope he doesn't bollucks it up.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the vote.I will post that is right to my knowledge gained over the years,which will be helpful or give some direction to move on for the person who posted the question.I have been active in this forum a week back ,so lots to learn on how to reply/post/gain points etc.

Comment: At the top of this web page, just left of the search box, are the letters Help.  They will lead you to the knowledge you seek.