# Difference between .equals ("0") and .equals('0')

Tags: java, string, equals

Context:

String comparison using equals with double quotes and single quotes

I tried checking the value of the field "parentId" (String) of one of my business objects as below:

```
System.out.println("Status 1 = "+myBusObj.getParentId().equals("0"));


System.out.println("Status 2 = "+myBusObj.getParentId().equals('0'));
```

I get the below output:

```
Status 1 = true //where parentId was of value 0 (String)

Status 2 = false //where parentId was of value 0 (String)
```

Problem:
Why `Status 1 is true` but `Status 2 is false`?

Comment: See difference between String and a character http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430043/difference-between-char-and-string-at-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case you are comparing with a one character `String`, and in the second case you are comparing with a `Character` object.

Strings and Characters are not comparable using `equals(Object)`; hence the `false` in the second case.

---

(There is a slight subtlety here ... in that `'0'` is a `char` literal that is being *autoboxed* to give you the `Character` object.  Prior to Java 5 where autoboxing was added to the language, the `.equals('0')` call would be a compilation error.  This is one of those examples where autoboxing is actually a hinderance ...)

Comment: You bring excellent points here, please also note that if OP uses `.equals(Character.toString('0'))`, it would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Status 1 : You try to compare string object to string object("String" String object) so result will be true.

Status 2 : You try to compare string object to character object('Character' character object) so that result will be false.

Thanks.

Comment: No ... it is a `Character` object.  The `char` type is a primitive type, and there is no `Char` class in the standard Java libraries.

Comment: yes @StephenC you are right, i just conveyed both objects are different.

Answer (score 0):

double quotes encloses Strings and single quotes encloses Chars.