# Swapping or moving elements of a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a 2D array of this format (matrix):

```
String[][] start;
start = new String[4][4];
```

**Input**

```
d d + +
a d d +
a b b c
+ b _ d
```

**Output**

```
d d + +
a d d +
a b b c
+ _ b d
```

The objective is to swap/move/shift the underscore ("_") around the array  except I cannot swap with a "+" character. I can only swap with the letters.

I'm trying to have other characters swap positions with the "_" but not replace them. I'm trying to have this operation occur in a loop

I don't know how to go about this. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

I changed the state of the array by swapping "_" with "b" on the last row. This is now a new array that I can compare to the initial state. I have to store the new state in another array to make a comparison to the initial state.

Comment: If you are only using characters I suggest to use `char[][] start`.

Comment: What are the benefits of using char over string in this case? @RenéScheibe

Comment: Because `char` better describes your input. For more details have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430043/difference-between-char-and-string-in-java.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. You ought to show what you've done so far. Also, be more clear about requirements. How, exactly, can an underscore move about within the array? What is the end result?

Comment: this is the inputs `d d + +
a d d +
a b b c
+ b _ d` can we see what is the output should look like?

Comment: @jdv the underscore can only move about the within the array using UP DOWN LEFT and RIGHT methods. The end result is to be able to compare the various states of every time the underscore moves to the initial state of the array.

Comment: @the_fro, you did not mention these methods in your question. See what I mean?

Comment: @jdv Yes I do. I'm a novice at this stuff. But, you were still right. I'll do better explaining next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two loops because you have 2d array and use an if to check if your value equal to `_` or not you can use this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] start = {{"d", "d", "+", "+"}, {"a", "d", "d", "+"}, {"a", "b", "b", "c"}, {"", "a", "_", "d"}};
    for (int i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < start[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(start[i][j] + " ");
            //here you should to check if your index is > 0 
            if (j > 0) {
                //here you make your swapping if your attribute = to _ 
                //and the previews value is not equal to + like you said in your question
                if (start[i][j].equals("_") && !start[i][j-1].equals("+")) {
                    String x = start[i][j - 1];
                    start[i][j - 1] = "_";
                    start[i][j] = x;
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    //print your result
    for (int i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < start[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(start[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The result is :

```
d d + + 
a d d + 
a b b c 
+ _ b d
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean by swapping and moving. But your array is basically just a grid of memory. You can only assign a new value to a cell. You cannot move values. If you want to do something other than assigning you need to build this operation. Like for moving that could be assigning the value to the new cell and than assigning null to the old cell. Swapping will in most cases require a temporary variable.

Comment: to swap the underscore with other letters in the matrix can I write a method for this? I understand that I'll need a temporary variable.

Answer (score -1):

Since your question is not clear about what do you expect after swapping `"_"` with other alphabet containing strings. I giving a skeleton program which may work for you.

```
String[][] start = new String[4][4];

for (int row = 0; row < start.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < start[row].length; column++) {
        if (start[row][column].equals("_")) {
            // you can swap character "_" with other alphabets
        }
    }
}
```

To check whether a string only contains alphabets or not, you can use the following.

```
if (start[row][column].matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
    // string contains only alphabets, now you do what you want to do
}
```

Particularly, you need to go through each row and column of the matrix and check if a string contains only alphabets or underscore. Then you can do swap but careful about the indices while accessing an element of the matrix.