# incomparable types: char and String

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    String inputEntry = in .nextLine();
    String inputCharacter = in .nextLine();
    if (inputCharacter.length() != 1) {
      System.out.println("Please enter single character");
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < inputEntry.length(); i++) {
        if (inputEntry.charAt(i) == inputCharacter) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("There is " + count + " occurence(s) of '" + inputCharacter + "' in " + inputEntry);
    }
  }
}
```

the above code gives error on line `if(inputEntry.charAt(i)==inputCharacter)`. how to solve this. The error shows that incomparable data types : char and string

Comment: st.nextLine(instead of nextLin) takes a string as an input.

Comment: In order to take a character as an input you may write in.next().charAt(0);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "char" and "String" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430043/difference-between-char-and-string-in-java)

Comment: Java is not JS. Do not use the "code snippet" tags. This is the second time you code has been fixed. Don't undo the changes. In the future, highlight your code and use the `{}` button to make sure the code retains its formatting.

Answer (score 1):

String and character are not comparable.

In java "a"(String) is not equal to 'a'(character).

`Scanner's nextLine()` takes input as an string.
Use `sc.next().charAt(0)` to take a character as an input.

Below is the working code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])                                                                      //scn=in
                                                                                                               // str=inputEntry
                                                                                                               // c=inputCharacter
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String");
        String inputEntry = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter charcter to know its occurrence");
        char inputCharacter = in.next().charAt(0);
        int count =0;


            for(int i=0;i<inputEntry.length();i++)
            {
                char ch = inputEntry.charAt(i);
                if(ch==inputCharacter)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            } 
            System.out.println("count is:"+count);
            System.out.println("There is "+count+" occurence(s) of '"+inputCharacter+"' in "+inputEntry);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
char inputCharacter = in.nextLine()
```

To

```
char inputCharacter = in.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Since `inputCharacter`  is `char` not `String`

This is modified code :-

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) // scn=in
                                         // str=inputEntry
                                         // c=inputCharacter
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String inputEntry = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter charcter to know its occurrence");
    char inputCharacter = in.nextLine().charAt(0);
    int count = 0;
                           // not needed that if statement. 

    for (int i = 0; i < inputEntry.length(); i++) {
      char ch = inputEntry.charAt(i);
      if (ch == inputCharacter) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("count is:" + count);
    System.out.println("There is " + count + " occurence(s) of '" + inputCharacter + "' in " + inputEntry);

  }
}
```

Output:-

```
Enter String
hello
Enter charcter to know its occurrence
l
count is:2
There is 2 occurence(s) of 'l' in hello
```